# MatToolTip: text disappear after 0.5 seconds since a put the pointer above

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanted to modify the font size that matTooltip has by default and in the documentation, I found that I can use `matTooltipClass="tooltip"`

It worked but after that, the hover text disappears immediately after hovering over the text.

here is my .html

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Grasp of the subject matter</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValueRubric1" name="criterian1" required>
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let rubric of criterian1"
            matTooltip="{{ rubric.criteria }}"
            matTooltipClass="tooltip"
            [value]="rubric"
          >
            {{ rubric.criteria }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

and this is my .scss

```
.mat-tooltip.tooltip {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

I would like the hover text to be displayed until I remove the mouse from it (which would be its normal behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I could not get `matTooltipClass` applied.

I used:

```css
.cdk-overlay-pane {  
  &.mat-tooltip-panel {  
   .mat-tooltip { 
    font-size: 20px !important;
    background: #b71c1c !important;
   } 
  } 
 }
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzmy43?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html